# How to switch Mainthread in C# Application

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I separate the Thread?

I used instance to run LoginForm.cs firstly, so, My first Thread in App is LoginForm.cs file,but I don't want to run LoginForm.cs's Thread anymore, After do login successfull, I want My app run Main Thread in MainInterface.cs, Meaning that, first Thread run LoginForm.cs, then stop Thread on LoginForm.cs, After logined corrected, then the Thread is running in MainInterface.cs.

I was follow by below code, But LoginForm.cs still a Main Thread:

**MainInterface.cs**

```
using System;

public class MainInterface : Form
{
   private static MainInterface Current;

   private MainInterface ()
   {
      if ( LoginForm.Instance != null )
         LoginForm.Instance.Close ();
   }

   public static MainInterface Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (Current == null)
         {
            Current = new MainInterface ();
         }
         return Current;
      }
   }
 }
```

**LoginForm.cs**

```
using System;

public class LoginForm: Form
{
   private static LoginForm Current;

   private LoginForm ()
   {

      if ( MainInterface.Instance != null )
         MainInterface.Instance.Close ();
   }

   public static LoginForm Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (Current == null)
         {
            Current = new LoginForm ();
         }
         return Current;
      }
   }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Myapp
{
   static class Program
   {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            LoginForm.Instance.ShowDialog ();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but besides that, can you make the question more clear? i don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: You are not using any `worker` Threads here I assume. Its just that you want to show a different dialog/form after successful login. Please correct if I am clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Program.cs**

```
using (Login login = new Login())
        { 
            login.ShowDialog(); //Close this form after login is correct in login form button_click
        }
        if (isValiduser == true) //Static variable created in application to check user
        {           
             Application.Run(new MainInterface());

        }
```

**Login form** click event

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              if(isValiduser == true)
               {
                  this.Close();
               }
             else
               {
                  //else part code
               }
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the DialogResult returned from ShowDialog rather than a public static field?

Comment: Excuse me!, Variable isValiduser declare in login form or Program.cs?

Comment: you can declare it in program.cs or can make another class to store login details eg:user_id,Name etc..so that you can access it globally